# AJAX - Cargar valores de .php en un select - Provincias

Tags: javascript, ajax, select

Tengo que cargar las provincias, están en un fichero .sql que cargo en el phpmyadmin, en un `select` dentro de un `formulario`.

El formulario tiene un `select` son la siguiente información:

```
<tr>
    <td align=right>Provincia:</td><td align=left colspan=3>
        <select name="provincia" id="idprovincia">
            <option value="-">Seleccione una Provincia...
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**¿Cómo cargo mediante AJAX las provincias en el select?**

He intentado lo siguiente pero me da el siguiente error, aunque creo que el código no es correcto:

```
jquery.js:18 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///D:/Javascript/OSMAR/provincias_exam.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Código intentado Javascript:

//Al cargar el documento...
$(document).ready(function(){
    iniciar();
    //Método 1.
    // $.ajax({
        // type: "GET",
        // url: "provincias_exam.php",
        // success: function (response){
            // $("#idprovincia").html(response).fadeIn();
        // }
    // });

    //Método 2.
    //$("#idprovincia").load("provincias_exam.php");
});//fin ready 


//Método 3.
var arrayProvincias = []; //array de objetos donde almacenaremos los datos de la consulta.
function iniciar(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'provincias_exam.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,  //Asíncrono
        success: resultadoPeticion, 
        error: function(){
            alert("Error en la petición a la base de datos");
        }
    });    
}


//Llamamos a la función para imprimir resultados.
function resultadoPeticion(resultados){ 
    var texto = "";
    //Recorremos los valores con un for each.
    $.each(resultados, function(indice, valor){
        texto += valor.nom_prov;
        arrayProvincias[arrayProvincias.length] = valor;
    });         
    //Agregamos en el id "idprovincia" el valor que tenga la variable texto. (todas las provincias).
    $("#idprovincia").html(texto);
    //Imprimimos todas las provincias en el select.
    rellenarSelect();
}


//Rellenamos el select con las provincias.
function rellenarSelect(){
    var imprimir = "";
    for (var i=0; i<arrayProvincias.length; i++){
        imprimir += "<option value='"+i+"'>"+arrayProvincias[i].nom_prov+"</option>";
    }
    $("#idprovincia").html(imprimir);
}
```

Archivo necesarios externos para la carga de las provincias:

**ComunidadesProvincias.sql** 
tabla `comunidades`

```
  id_com | nom_com
    1    | 'Euskadi'
    2    |'Galicia'
    3    |'Catalunya'
    4    |'Andalucia'
    5    | 'Castilla Leon'
    6    | 'Castilla La MAncha'
```

la tabla `provincias`

```
id_prov`| `id_com`| `nom_prov`
    1   |        1| 'Bizkaia'
    2   |        1| 'Gipuzkoa'
    3   |        1| 'Araba'
    4   |        2| 'A Coruña'
    5   |        2| 'Lugo'
    6   |        2| 'Ourense'
    7   |        2| 'Pontevdra'
    8   |        3| 'Barcelona'
    9   |        3| 'Tarragona'
    10  |        3| 'Lleida'
    11  |        3| 'Girona'
    12  |        4| 'Almeria'
    13  |        4| 'Cadiz'
    14  |        4| 'Cordoba'
    15  |        4| 'Granada'
    16  |        4| 'Huelva'
```

**conexion2.php:**

```
<?

$dbserver = "nombre_servidor";
$dbuser = "usuario";
$password = "clave";
$dbname = "nombre_base_datos";


$con = new mysqli($dbserver, $dbuser, $password,$dbname);
if(!$con) {
    echo "No se pudo conectar a la base de datos";
  }

?>
```

**provincias_exam.php:**

```
<?php
    include("conexion_2.php");


if(!$con) {
    echo "No se pudo conectar a la base de datos";
  }


$sql = "SELECT * FROM provincias";
$result = $con->query($sql);

$rowdata=array();
$i=0;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array())
        {
            $rowdata[$i]=$row;
            $i++;           
        }
echo json_encode($rowdata);
?>
```

Comment: ¿Estás devolviendo las provincias como JSON? Si es así solo necesitas recorrerlas y en cada iteración crear un `option` que representará a la provincia actual.

Comment: Ese error es normalmente porque no encontró el archivo para cargar, te aseguraste que esta sea la ruta correcta de tu archivo? `///D:/Javascript/OSMAR/provincias_exam.php`

Comment: Sí es la ruta correcta debido a que estoy en la misma ruta, tengo la misma ruta para el archivo .js, como para el archivo .html como para el archivo .php y .sql

Comment: La ruta es "rara" Una pregunta curiosa,  está ejecutando `php` desde un servidor apache?  Donde están los archivos de su aplicación?  Si es así verificar sus rutas, pareciera que no lo están por eso no se puede ejecutar el archivo `php`

Comment: Cierto. Lo estaba haciendo desde el local jajaja, ya lo agregé al localhost con xampp, no me da error de ruta pero no funciona.

Comment: Cuál de todos los métodos para las llamadas ajax está utilizando ?

Comment: El último, el que está descomentado. Método 3.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con esto.

Lo he puesto todo en una sola función, porque crear funciones que sólo se llaman una vez creo que no hace falta.

```
function iniciar(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'provincias_exam.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(){
            alert("Error en la petición a la base de datos");
        }
    }).done( function(valor) {
       var texto = "";
       //Recorremos los valores con un for each.
       $.each(function(i, valor){
           texto += "<option value='"+i+"'>"+valor+"</option>";
       });         
       //Agregamos en el id "idprovincia" el valor que tenga la variable texto. (todas las provincias).
       $("#idprovincia").html(texto);
    });    
}
```

Comment: Con este código me aparece en pantalla el mensaje de error: " alert("Error en la petición a la base de datos");" pero en la consola no me da errores ninguno. No me carga las provincias en el select.

Comment: No sé revisar el network, ¿cómo se realiza?

Comment: En el navegador presiona la tecla `F12` una vez dentro selecciona la pestaña Network http://imgur.com/a/vtZIx y  ahí debe mostrar la llamada al archivo `php` Así http://imgur.com/a/gXkXH , y luego das click ahí y debe mostrar   Un menú así http://imgur.com/a/6rAsN  , debes ir a response y ver que te está devolviendo el servidor.

Comment: No me muestra ninguna llamada al fichero .php... Creo que ahí está el error. ¿Chat?

Comment: Revisa también el log del Apache, tanto el `access.log` como el `error.log` por si tuvieras algún tipo de error en el código, o en la llamada al fichero php desde el Ajax. ¿Que utilizabas Xampp,Wampp, ...?

Comment: Utilizo Xampp. Me funcionan todos los ejercicios que tengo en xampp, porque el código está bien programado, pero en este ejercicio creo que es problema del código, de la sintaxis. El servidor me funciona bien.

Comment: El fichero `provincias_exam.php` lo tienes en la misma carpeta que el html ? Prueba a hacer lo siguiente en firefox **antes** de que se ejecute el Ajax pulsar `ALT+SHIFT+S` y seleccionas la pestaña Red. Luego refrescas o pulsas el botón que toque para que se ejecute el Ajax. Ahora revisa toda la ventana buscando la llamada al `provincias_exam.php`. Si no sale es que no se está ejecutando el Ajax y deberías mirar porque no se ejecuta esa parte del JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Ésta sería la solución a tu consulta. Sin embargo toma en cuenta las lineas comentadas. Tal vez te ayuden a encontrar y entender mejor el error en tu código. Saludos.

```
function obtenerProvincias() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'provincias_exam.php', //Si el doc php esta en mismo nivel seria directo. Caso contrario si el archivos php esta en una carpeta abría que mapearla bien. Ejemplo: url:'php/provincias_Exam.php'
            type: 'post',
            success: function (r) { // te recomiendo que imprimas las respuesta "console.log(r)" para que veas como te esta devolviendo la estructura tu php.
                $("#idprovincia").empty();
                r = JSON.parse(r);
                sedeItem = crearElemento('option', '__', '__', 'Seleccione...', '__', '__');
                sedeItem.setAttribute('value', '');
                $("#idprovincia").append(sedeItem);
                for (i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                    option = crearElemento('option', '__', '__', r[i]['id_prov'], '__', r[i]['nom_prov']);
                    $("#idprovincia").append(option);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function crearElemento(elemento, identificador, clase, texto, ruta, valor) {
        item = document.createElement(elemento);
        if (identificador !=='__'){ item.id = identificador; }
        if (clase !=='__') { item.className = clase; }
        if (texto !=='__') { item.innerText = texto; }
        if (ruta !== '__') { item.dataset.cargarVista = ruta; }
        if (valor !== '__') { item.value = valor; }
        return item;
    }
```

Comment: No me da ningún error pero tampoco me muestra nada en el console.log(r)... qué extraño, Despliego el "select" y no aparece nada.

Comment: Puedes subir un pantallazo de tu resultado? Es que quiero ver que te sale en la consola cuando te responde el ajax. Puede ser que no este llegando tu petición al doc php. Tienes algún modo de hacer debug a tu php?

Comment: Sí, desde network pero parece que no coge el fichero .php, la ruta es la misma donde está el archivo .html, así que es muy extraño.

Comment: ¿no tengo más ayuda?

Comment: Puedo crear una estructura de prueba y te lo paso. 